# Can this proof for a Fourier series be made more rigorous?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, fourier-series

Given that
$$\sum_n e^{ikan}=C\sum_m \delta(k-2\pi m/a)\tag{1}$$
for $k\in\mathbb R,a\neq0\in\mathbb R,n\in \mathbb Z, m\in\mathbb Z$, I want to prove that $C=2\pi/|a|$.

**Proof**

First integrate both sides of $(1)$ over the interval $[-\pi/a,\pi/a]$:
$$\int_{-\pi/a}^{\pi/a}\mathrm dk\sum_n e^{ikan}=C.\tag{2}$$
Now we can switch the sum and the integration symbol
$$\sum_n\int_{-\pi/a}^{\pi/a}\mathrm dk\,e^{ikan}=C.\tag{3}$$
Next evaluate  the integral
$$\int_{-\pi/a}^{\pi/a}\mathrm dk\,e^{ikan}=\frac{2}{an}\sin(n\pi)\tag{4}$$
For $n\neq 0$ this last expression is zero. For $n=0$ we can say
$$\frac{2}{an}\sin(n\pi)=\frac{2}{a}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(x \pi)}{x}=\frac{2\pi}{a}.\tag{5}$$
Summarized
$$\int_{-\pi/a}^{\pi/a}\mathrm dk\,e^{ikan}=\begin{cases}\frac{2\pi}{a} & n=0 \\0, & n \neq  0.\end{cases}\tag{6}$$

Finally take the sum
\begin{align}C&=\sum_n\int_{-\pi/a}^{\pi/a}\mathrm dk e^{ikan}\tag{7}\\
&=\sum_n \begin{cases}\frac{2\pi}{a}& n=0,\\0&n \neq  0.\end{cases}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{a}
\end{align}
I'm especially uncertain about the steps where I

1. Switch summation and integration,
2. Equate $\sin (n\pi)/n$ to its limit when $n=0$,
3. I'm supposed to get $|a|$ but instead I just get $a$.

Comment: To allow people to comment with efficient clarity it would be helpful if you added equation numbers to all your steps. An infinite sum has to be absolutely convergent to rigorously switch sum and integral so unless you can find a way around, I suspect your falling at the first fence.

Comment: For 2: Evaluate the integral directly in the case of $n=0$ (hint: you are just integrating the constant $1$ function) and give $(4)$ for the case that $n \neq 0$. When $n=0$ think about the case $a<0$ carefully.